# Reading a file while running a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I am having difficulty running this program without creating a logic error. I was wondering if someone could explain to me whats wrong. My code for the file WORKS:

```
def main():
    myfile = open('tests.txt','w')
    print('Enter six tests and scores or Enter to exit')
    print('--------------------------') #I added this feature to make the code
    #more structured
    testName = input('Enter test name: ')
    while testName != '':
        score = int(input('Enter % score of this test: ')) 
        myfile.write(str(score) + '\n')
        testName = input('Enter test name: ')  
        myfile.write(testName + '\n')
    myfile.close()
    print('File was created successfully')
main()
```

But this code that I run to read and output the file is giving me a logic error. I know that the code is promptly written, but I don't know what is going. Can you please check my code and advise me why its not working.: this is the code

```
def main():
    myfile = open('tests.txt','r')
    print('Reading six tests and scores')
    print('Test\t               Score')
    print('----------------------------')
    test_score = 0
    counter = 0 #for number of tests
    line = myfile.readline()
    while line != '':
         name = line.rstrip('\n')
         score = int(myfile.readline())
         test_score += score
         print(name, score)
         line = myfile.readline()
         counter += 1
    myfile.close()
    average = test_score/ counter
    print('Average is',format(average,'.1f'))
main()
```

Input/output for the first program should be
Entering six tests and scores
Enter test name objects
Enter % score on this test 88
Enter test name loops
Enter % score on this test 95
Enter test name selections
Enter % score on this test 86
Enter test name variables
Enter % score on this test 82
Enter test name files
Enter % score on this test 100
Enter test name functions
Enter % score on this test 80
File was created successfully

output for the second program that reads the file should be:

Reading six tests and scores
TEST          SCORE
objects                88
loops                   95
selections           86
variables             82
files                   100
functions             80
Average is 88.5

Comment: What output are you getting and what is the desire output? Show us how you know there is a logic error

Comment: Error message is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ab\Desktop\chapter 6\program 6_2.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ab\Desktop\chapter 6\program 6_2.py", line 11, in main
    score = int(myfile.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Comment: Input for the first file should be -- Entering six tests and scores
Enter test name objects
Enter % score on this test 88
Enter test name loops
Enter % score on this test 95
Enter test name selections
Enter % score on this test 86
Enter test name variables
Enter % score on this test 82
Enter test name files
Enter % score on this test 100
Enter test name functions
Enter % score on this test 80
File was created successfully

Comment: out for the second program should be ----Reading six tests and scores
TEST          SCORE
objects                88
loops                   95
selections           86
variables             82
files                   100
functions             80
Average is 88.5

Comment: You write score then name, but try to read name then score. Also, you should strip() the stuff you are going to cast to int. Add a few prints to verify input or run this with a debugger.

Comment: @ABerrio that should all go in the question not the comments

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. The first one is before your while loop in the write function.  You are taking the test name as input, but not writing it to the file.

Writing the test name to the text file before the while loop solves your first problem but then leaves you with another.  The way you are adding the new lines makes you end up with empty lines at the end of the file that you are then trying to read.  Move the new line to the front of what is being written.

```
    testName = input('Enter test name: ')
    myfile.write(testName)
    while testName != '':
        score = int(input('Enter % score of this test: '))
        myfile.write('\n' + str(score))
        testName = input('Enter test name: ')
        myfile.write('\n' + testName)
    myfile.close()
    print('File was created successfully')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reason, the second program is still giving me an error. I added the change to it. I am very new to programing.

Comment: This is odd.  When I run both functions with the changes I posted I get no errors.  Just to be sure there wasn't a misunderstanding, you did replace the code after the second 'print' in your first main() function with the code I posted, right?

Comment: Added the edit you recommended and I am surprised that it made a huge difference.The program runs beautifully and works perfectly now! Thanks a lot. Is there a way to send a private message on this site? I was wondering if I could ask you a couple of questions. I want to improve my coding abilities.